# How do I repair my dual boot windows 7 and windows 8 bootloader?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, multi-boot

I had my laptop running both Windows 7 and Windows 8 as a dual boot. When I would start it, it would show the nice OS selection screen.

Then, I reinstalled Windows 7. What happens now is that when I start my laptop, there's no OS selection screen, it loads Windows 7 right away.

The Windows 8 partition is still there, I can see it in My PC, so I guess it's a matter of fixing the dual boot. However I can't find how to do that in this case.

How do I repair my dual boot windows 7 and windows 8 bootloader?

Answer (score 1):

Get a WinPE boot disk or a MSDaRT boot disk and use BCDEdit. It's a command-line tool for managing BCD stores. It can be used for all kinds of stuff, including creating new stores, modifying existing stores, adding boot menu options, and for fixing stuff like this. BCDEdit is like Bootcfg.exe on earlier versions of Windows but better.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: But if my system is loading fine Windows 7, do I need a boot disk? Can't I just use the BCDEdit tool?

Comment: You need to repair the WIndows 8 bootloader, use WINPE to do this.

Comment: Using bcdedit can only add boot entry in BCD for Win 8 but it cannot fix boot for Windows 8. Boot manager (and other boot related files) should be fixed too! Windows 8 boot loader (winload.exe) does not need fixing it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

"Dual-boot Repair" tool (comes with Visual BCD Editor) can fix the issue automatically on click.

Just click Dual-boot Repair -> "Automatic Repair".
It will add Windows 8 to boot menu and fix boot files for dual-booting Win 7 and Win 8.

Visual BCD Editor can be downloaded from http://www.boyans.net

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I am resurrecting this thread, but I thought maybe this might be helpful to others.

Your problem may be that your boot options are fine, but your bootmgr has a timeout set to 0. This will cause your bootmgr to appear to be skipped as it will choose your {default} boot option right away.

Same applies as above. You will need to get to a command line.
if you just type **bcdedit** and press enter, you can review your current bootmgr and boot options. Under the {bootmgr} section look for your timeout setting. If it is set to 0 you can use the following to set it to something >0.

**bcdedit /set {bootmgr} timeout 10**

This will set your timer to 10 seconds. (You can use any value that you like)

To confirm the change, just type **bcdedit** and press enter to review your options again.
Best of luck!

(Please note that you can boot your PC up to any Windows Install disk, press the Repair option, choose Advanced options, Command Line Prompt)

Comment: After you install an earlier Windows version in dual boot, booting to later Windows version is messed up. Read what OP says first then write/post. Nothing to do with timeout! So -1.